# vcxproj additional include path that are not shown in the project properties

Tags: c++, visual-studio, properties, projects-and-solutions, include-path

I changed the path of my VS2017 project. Despite the fact that I updated every additional or include path under my project properties, I noticed that inside the *.vcxproj file are exist some additional include directories `<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>` from my previous project path. These additional paths are not shown inside the properties manager.

For example additionalIncludePath inside vcxproj below, it belongs to previous project's path.

```
<ResourceCompile>
  <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_WINDOWS;</PreprocessorDefinitions>
  <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>D:\Software\hor_earlyversions\revision-1\source\;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
</ResourceCompile>
```

I found also `<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>` under `<Midl>` tags.

So my questions are :

a) why I can not see them under project properties

b) do I have to delete them manually ?

[image]

Comment: Configuration Properties -> Resources -> General -> Additional Include Directories

Comment: I have the same problem with all projects inside my solution. Some of them does not have any resources. When I choose "Go to definition" VS gives me two files, the one that routes to the old path and an other with the new path. To fix that, I replaced the paths manually but I wonder if there is an automated way to this under the VS2017 GUI.